# Google AppScript GetRange Shorten Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering if there was any way I could shorten the script below? As you can see, I copied the eight lines (B13-I13) to make a new one with a different row (B4-I14). However, I must continue it until row 23.

```
var values = [[formS.getRange("C7").getValue(),
              formS.getRange("C8").getValue(),
              formS.getRange("D9").getValue(),

              formS.getRange("B13").getValue(), <--- shorten this
              formS.getRange("C13").getValue(),
              formS.getRange("D13").getValue(), 
              formS.getRange("E13").getValue(), 
              formS.getRange("F13").getValue(),   
              formS.getRange("G13").getValue(),   
              formS.getRange("H13").getValue(),
              formS.getRange("I13").getValue(), ----> to this

              formS.getRange("B14").getValue(), <--- shorten this
              formS.getRange("C14").getValue(),
              formS.getRange("D14").getValue(), 
              formS.getRange("E14").getValue(), 
              formS.getRange("F14").getValue(),   
              formS.getRange("G14").getValue(),   
              formS.getRange("H14").getValue(),
              formS.getRange("I14").getValue(), ----> to this
]];
```

This is the script that I'm using..

```
function SaveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  --> LOCATION OF THE SCRIPT ABOVE <---

  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11).setValues(values);
  ClearCell();
}
```

Please see the sample picture below where I encode the data.
[image]

This is the sample image of the sheet where the data were being saved.
[image]

[SAMPLE SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L8aKA50RgMX850VH-toKZ0glcuE8VPh2WZCsR_YLINw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Tanaike hi! I updated the question above with the rest of the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function sample() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var values = [
    ...formS.getRange("C7:C8").getValues().flat(),
    formS.getRange("D9").getValue(),
    ...formS.getRange("B13:I23").getValues().flat()
  ];
  dataS.appendRow(values);
}
```

- From `However, I must continue it until row 23.`, I used `B13:I23`.
- In this modification, the values of "C7:C8" and "D9" and "B13:I23" of "Form" sheet are copied to the last row of "Data" sheet as one row.

Comment: I'm currently having this error: `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 3 but the range has 11.`

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your error message of `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 3 but the range has 11.`, I think that in this case, the reason of this is due to the script you are not showing. So in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your whole script for replicating your issue?

Comment: I already update the question above. Please see. Thank you!

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for adding script. `values` in your showing script is the 2-dimensional array including one element. So my proposed modified script also uses this. But from your replying, it seems that your expected `values` is different from your current script. And your added script is trying to put the values of 1 row and 11 columns. But your showing `values` is 1 row and 19 columns. So I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. So can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: I posted an image above which I use to enter the data. I need to save the data from B13 - I23 on that part.

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. From your additional image, in this case, the values of "C7", "C8" and "D9" are not used. And, you want to copy "B13:I23" of "Form" sheet to the last row of "Data" sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: C7, C8, and D9 will also be saved as per the script. I'm trying to save the data on B13:I23 with a shorten script since I didn't want to copy and paste the 8 lines again and again.

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. From your replying and the additional image, I added one more script. Could you please confirm it? By the way, I cannot understand `C7, C8, and D9 will also be saved as per the script.`. Can you provide the sample output situation as the image?

Comment: I updated the question above. Hope it helps!

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for achieving from your sample input to the sample output situations. Can I ask you about the detail of your logic?

Comment: @cjwrk For example, where are the values of the columns "A" to "D" in the output situation from? And, you want to copy the values of "B13:I23" of "Form" sheet to the column "D" the last row of "Data" sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Columns "A to C" in the "Data" sheet correspond to "C7, C8, and D9". The data on B13 of the "Form" sheet, on the other hand, should be in column D of the Data sheet. One column on the Data sheet equals one cell on the Form sheet.

Comment: @cjwrk From your updated question, by guessing your goal, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Just saw your modified script. It saved but it should be saved in one row. The column in my Data sheet is up to column CF.

Comment: I included the sample spreadsheet above. Please see.

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @cjwrk In this modification, from `However, I must continue it until row 23.`, the values of "B13:I23" are used. But when you want to put the values to the column "CF", please modify "B13:I23" to "B13:I22".

Comment: It works now. Thank you!

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.